# Como alterar o zoom em uma determinada localização no google maps api v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firebase, google-maps-api-3

Estou tentando fazer com que o map dee zoom em um determinado local de markers, quando eles são criados no Firebase.

Eu já tentei utlizar o

```
setZoom()
setCenter()
```

**porém o que acontece é isto:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria que ele fosse em cima da localização correta,
por exemplo: Tem um markers do Barra Shopping, ele vai direto para o barra shopping.

O que eu tentei foi o seguinte:

**GM.js**

```
function initMap() {
  var map;
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -1.000, lng: 62.000},
    mapTypeId: 'hybrid',
    zoom: 2,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
    },
    streetViewControl: false,
    rotateControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false,
    styles: [
        {
          "featureType": "administrative",
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [
            {
              "visibility": "off"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "featureType": "poi",
          "stylers": [
            {
              "visibility": "off"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "featureType": "road",
          "elementType": "labels.icon",
          "stylers": [
            {
              "visibility": "off"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "featureType": "transit",
          "stylers": [
            {
              "visibility": "off"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
  });
  generateMarkerDBS();
  searchAllMarkers(map);

}
```

**firebase.js**

```
function searchAllMarkers(map){
    var locations = firebase.database().ref('/').child('aliansce');

    locations.on('value', function(keysSnapshot){

        // SE CONTER LOCAIS DA COMPANIA
        // IRÁ MOSTRAR OS MAKERS NO MAPA
        if(keysSnapshot.numChildren() > 0){
            locations.on('child_added', function(keysSnapshot){
                var markersCoordinatesNodes = firebase.database().ref('/aliansce/').child('' + keysSnapshot.key + '/marker/markerCoordinates/');
                markersCoordinatesNodes.on('value', function(coordinatesSnapshot){
                    if((coordinatesSnapshot.val().lat == null) && (coordinatesSnapshot.val().lng == null)){
                        alert("LAT ou LNG NULL's no DATABASE!!");
                    } else {
                        var markersDateNodes = firebase.database().ref('/aliansce/'+ keysSnapshot.key + '/marker/markerDateCreate/').child('dateDescription');
                        markersDateNodes.on('value', function(dateSnapshot){
                            var infowindow = [];
                            var arrMarkers = [];
                            var arrMarkers = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: new google.maps.LatLng(coordinatesSnapshot.val().lat,coordinatesSnapshot.val().lng),
                                map: map,
                                title: keysSnapshot.key
                            });
                            map.setZoom(15);
                            map.panTo(arrMarkers.position);
                            arrMarkers.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                position: new google.maps.LatLng(coordinatesSnapshot.val().lat,coordinatesSnapshot.val().lng),
                                content: 
                                '<div><strong>'+ keysSnapshot.key +'</strong><br></div>'+
                                '<div>'+ dateSnapshot.val() +'</div>',
                            });
                            arrMarkers.infowindow.open(map,arrMarkers);
                            arrMarkers.addListener('click', function(event,infowindow){
                                this.infowindow.open(map,arrMarkers);
                            });

                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        } else {
            alert("NÃO CONTÉM LOCAIS DA COMPANIA NO DATABASE");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: no codigo nao tem nenhum setCenter, nao ei como testou mas é comum o pessoal usar o  `setCenter()` sem parametros, tenta algo assim `setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(coordinatesSnapshot.val().lat,coordinatesSnapshot.val().lng))`

Comment: @NeuberOliveira desculpe eu devo ter colado o código quando dei ctrl+z.. Então eu tentei isso e o que ocorreu foi aquele zoom errado. Eu acho que ele não está nem pegand oo valores do zoom, porque eu deixei um center dentro do mapa.

Comment: Você está primeiro dando setCenter e depois SetZoom?

Comment: e onde voce chamou o `setCenter`? so pra deixar claro as coordenadas do seu `setCenter`devem ser as mesmas do marker que voce quer "focar"

Comment: Gente já consegui, obrigado pessoal !